# FILE I/O operations. Clearing the elements of an structure

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread

I'm a begginer but I'm basically creating a program that opens a binary file containing 'parts' structure, reads the structure
into an array, sets the on_hand member of each structure to 0, and then writes the structure back to the file. Here's my code:

***invclear.c***

```
/* Modifies a file of part records by setting the quantity
   on hand to a zero for all records */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_LEN 25
#define MAX_PARTS 100

struct part {                //size= 36 bytes (2 holes in between number and name[] array
    int number;
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    int on_hand;
    }inventory[MAX_PARTS];               

int num_parts;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;

    if((fp=fopen("clear_sample.c", "rb+")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open inventory file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    num_parts = fread(inventory, sizeof(struct part), MAX_PARTS, fp);    //reads the contents


    for(i=0; i<num_parts; i++)
        inventory[i].on_hand=0;         //clears them

    rewind(fp);                         //sets file position at beggining

    fwrite(inventory,sizeof(struct part), num_parts, fp); 
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

***clear_sample.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_LEN 25
#define MAX_PARTS 100

struct part {
    int number;
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    int on_hand;
    }inventory[MAX_PARTS]={0};


int main()
{
    int i;
    int num_parts;

    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
        inventory[i].on_hand=i;

    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
        printf("%d\n",inventory[i].on_hand);

    return 0;
}
```

It runs without errors but unfortunately *it's not clearing the on_hand variable to 0, in fact it's deleting almost the whole file*. This is the modified ***clear_sample.c*** file that I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <st
```

Any ideas into why am I doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a C source file that clearly does not contain data as a binary data file?  And what exactly do you think will happen when you read a binary file that explicitly has a '0' at byte 34 as a text file?  (hint: take a look at how big the file is)

Comment: So that was the problem, I feel stupid now. How can I fix this, is there any way to convert that file to binary?

Comment: All files are binary.  Some binary files make sense as text if you put only printable characters in them.  This is typically not what you get if you fwrite arbitrary binary data into a file.  Don't use a C source file as a data file.  Create a dedicated binary data file, swap "clear_sample.c" for "data.bin" or something.  You will probably want to make sure it's big enough to store your 100 parts

Comment: btw, on a 32 bit architecure this structure: `{ int, char[26], int }` will not have a hole between the 1st int and the char array.  There will be a 2 byte hole between the array and the 2nd int.  You could increase your name length to 27 chars for "free".

Comment: You should probably read your assignment again, I'm sure you have misunderstood something. There must be a binary file somewhere which you are supposed to be reading, or maybe you need to create one yourself.

Comment: Yeah there's no binary file provided or anything, I 'm not getting the question. "Modifies a file of part records by setting the quantity on hand to a zero for all records".

Comment: Sure.  A binary file is not special.  Any random 3600 bytes (which you could literally get from /dev/random) would produce a file that your program would happily read as 100 part records.  The individual part data would be absolute rubbish of course but your program won't care.  (You might).  Try writing 3600 'X' to your data file, run your program and then open the file in a hex editor

Comment: Probably I need to create a binary file of part records? Would I'l do it like this  struct{ int records[5] } ?

Comment: Oh so just putting random numbers on any text editor.. I'll try to do that.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you read the data for a `struct part` from a file that does not contain the data for a `struct part`, but actually contains C source code? (What happens is that you read the same amount of C source code, and store it in a `struct part`, then change it, then write it back)

Answer (score 2):

You have been misled by whatever tool you used to inspect the resulting file. It is not

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <st
```

In fact it is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <std^@^@^@^@h>

#define NAME_LEN 25
#define ^@^@^@^@PARTS 100

struct part {
    int^@^@^@^@ber;
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
^@^@^@^@int on_hand;
    }inventory[MAX_^@^@^@^@S]={0};


int main()
{
    int i^@^@^@^@  int num_parts;

    for(i=1;i<^@^@^@^@i++)
        inventory[i].on_han^@^@^@^@

    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
       ^@^@^@^@ntf("%d\n",inventory[i].on_hand)^@^@^@^@   return 0;
}
```

All those `^@` are binary zero bytes, corresponding to zeroes you've put into `on_hand`.

As mentioned in comments, to test your program prepare a file which does obey the format you expect.

Comment: And the good news is, once he has an appropriate data file, his program will probably work.